# How to properly format rows and columns in an excel sheet exported from parsed items in .txt file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, text-parsing

I'm trying to create an excel sheet using data made up from specific, recurring blocks of text in a .txt file and ignoring all other data in the file (table of contents, etc). The blocks of text are in the format shown here and I'm having two different issues with the output in the final excel sheet.

> ITEMNAME
> Status: StatusItem
> Category: CategoryItem
> Sub-Category: SubcategoryItem
> Date: MM/dd/yyyy
> Frequency: FrequenceItem
> Language: LanguageItem
> Description: DescriptionText

Currently, my code is using a dictionary made by searching for a block pattern, inserting it into a data-frame (pandas) and exporting to excel. The issue I'm having, however, is that it creates a new row for each line in the text block rather than creating a new row for each block. Shown here:

[Excel sheet with extra rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Th1U.png)

How can I prevent this with my block pattern?

The second issue is that the top item ("ITEMNAME") is not in the same format as it doesn't have a "key" to use in the dictionary. How would I include it in the block pattern to add to the dictionary and export being in a different format?

Note: the text file I'm reading from contains a table of contents, footers and other data that has to be excluded which is why I've tried to use a block pattern to only grab what is needed

Here is my code as it stands.

```
import pandas as pd
import re


txtFilePath = r'/test.txt'

with open(txtFilePath, 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

# define pattern for block search - first method
block_pattern = re.compile(r"^(?:Status|Event Category|Event Sub-Category|"
                           r"Added Date|Update Frequency|Language|Description):.+$",
                           re.MULTILINE)


# find all blocks that match the pattern
blocks = block_pattern.findall(text)

df = pd.DataFrame()


# iterate over blocks and extract patterns
for block in blocks:
    # split blocks on individual lines
    lines = block.strip().split("\n")
    # dict to store items for this block
    item_dict = {}

    # iterate to find type and values
    for line in lines:
        item_parts = line.strip().split(":", 1)
        item_type = item_parts[0].strip()
        item_value = item_parts[1].strip()

        # add item to dict
        item_dict[item_type] = item_value

    df = df.append(item_dict, ignore_index=True)

# print(df)
df.to_excel(r'/text.xlsx')
```

I've tried two changes to the append line to fix the extra rows.

First change:  `df.loc[0] = df.append(item_dict, ignore_index=True)` but it gives this error:

> ValueError: cannot set row with mismatched columns

Second Change:  `df.loc[0] = item_dict`
This change creates the columns but imports no data from the dictionary. The excel sheet has columns but nothing else.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

**EDIT**

Example Text:

> Institution 123
> Status: Production
> Event Category: News
> Event Sub-Category: N/A
> Added Date: 5/10/2017
> Update Frequency: Weekly
> Language: English
> Description: Local financial institution

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32NHN.png)

**EDIT**
I've managed to get everything exported in the rows properly. The only issue I'm currently running into is that the last field (Description) is sometimes more than one line so I can't use a simple \n in the block pattern. There is always a blank line after the end of the final field so is there a way to split on the empty line? That should encapsulate the entire field properly but I can't seem to regex it correctly.

Working Code:

```
with open(txtFilePath, 'r') as f:
text = "".join(f)
       
block_pattern = re.compile(
    r"^(.*)\n"
    r"^Status: (.*)\n"
    r"^Event Category: (.*)\n"
    r"^Event Sub-Category: (.*)\n"
    r"^Added Date: (.*)\n"
    r"^Update Frequency: (.*)\n"
    r"^Language: (.*)\n"
    r"^Description: (.*)\n",
    flags=re.MULTILINE)

columns = ["Item", "Status", "Event Category", "Event Sub-Category",
           "Added Date", "Update Frequency", "Language", "Description"]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(re.findall(block_pattern, text), columns=columns)

df.to_excel(test.xlsx)
```

I've tried

```
r"^Description: (.*)\n\*s\n"
```

and

```
r"^Description: (.*)\n\r\n"
```

for the final field but both attempts make the excel file completely empty so its likely not recognizing the pattern

Comment: Can you share a  _minimal reproducible example_ **as text** and a  clear expected output ?

Comment: Just added an example and my desired outcome

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach with [`pandas.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html).

Try this :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(txtFilePath, header=None)
​
df = (
       df
        [0].str.split(":", expand=True)
        .set_index(0)
        .transpose() # <-- long to wide
        .assign(Name= df.iloc[0,0])
        .pipe(lambda x: x.reindex(columns= ["Name"] + x.columns.tolist()[:-1]))
      )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df.to_string())

0             Name Institution 123       Status Event Category Event Sub-Category  Added Date Update Frequency  Language                   Description
1  Institution 123            None   Production           News                N/A   5/10/2017           Weekly   English   Local financial institution
```

Finally, to make an Excel spreadsheet, you can add `df.to_excel(r"/text.xlsx")`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused by this. which portion is this replacing?

Comment: The whole code you shared. You can run this one to get directly your expected output.